# How to mock multiple methods of same class in grails using spock?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, spock

I have a unit test in which I want to mock two methods of a service. I know how to do it once :

```
def caseHistoryMock = mockFor(CaseHistoryService)
        caseHistoryMock.demand.getLatestCaseHistory(1..1) {String caseNumber, String productFamily -> return caseHistoryObj }
        controller.caseHistoryService = caseHistoryMock.createMock()
```

How do I mock another method of caseHistoryService. The calls to methods in my controller are as follows :

```
def caseHistoryObj = caseHistoryService.getLatestCaseHistory(alert.caseNumber, alert.productFamily)
```

and

```
caseHistoryService.saveCaseHistory(caseHistoryMap)
```

*I am using grails 2.5.1.
Thanks in advance,
Apoorv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock it with `Mock` function:

```
def caseHistoryMock = Mock(CaseHistoryService)
1 * caseHistoryMock.getLatestCaseHistory(_, _) >> caseHistoryObj
1 * caseHistoryMock.saveCaseHistory(_)
controller.caseHistoryService = caseHistoryMock
```

The `1 *` is optional and describs how often the function should be called.